# firebase push notification using node js-getting error

Tags: node.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
console.log(serviceAccount);

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://my_project_id-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app"
});

const message = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Hello from Firebase!',
        body: 'This is a push notification from Firebase.'
    },
    token: 'ekBu_n:APA91bEAXiyJvEbk5Vb4u7tJgCjFXGHL6sNypCgYTP3qPfy1nC2Sw9Q7H6zRDo8-AM31l6GI-twJe72t4z4k-hGy1KNgtpsWaXeP2tieH_J7XyZYDr5LWevh5g2TnOhEgNafnW0t-o0d' // Replace with the specific device token
};

// Send the message
admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Notification sent successfully:', response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sending notification:', error);
    });
```

this is my app.js code. when I run this code I am getting error like below.
Error sending notification: FirebaseMessagingError: SenderId mismatch
at Function.fromServerError (D:\firebase_notification_demo\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:254:16)
at createFirebaseError (D:\firebase_notification_demo\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\messaging\messaging-errors-internal.js:35:47)
at D:\firebase_notification_demo\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\messaging\messaging-api-request-internal.js:79:75
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
errorInfo: {
code: 'messaging/mismatched-credential',
message: 'SenderId mismatch'
},
codePrefix: 'messaging'
} please help me to solve this problem to send push notication.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading firebase-messaging in Android Studio at `build.gradle`

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging
```

If that doesn't work, please double check if the Server ID in Firebase Project Setting is matching the one that you already got!

If that doesn't work try updating `google-service.json` with a new one.

Answer (score -2):

The error message you're encountering, "SenderId mismatch," usually occurs when the Sender ID in the FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) configuration doesn't match the Sender ID associated with the FCM token used for sending the push notification. To resolve this issue, please follow these steps:

1. **Check Your Project Configuration**:
   Make sure you are using the correct Firebase project configuration in your `serviceAccountKey.json` file and that it matches the project where you obtained the FCM token.
2. **Check Your Sender ID**:
   Verify that the `databaseURL` and `projectId` in your `serviceAccountKey.json` match the actual settings of your Firebase project. You can find the correct `projectId` in your Firebase project settings.
3. **Check FCM Token**:
   Double-check that the FCM token (`message.token`) you're using to send the notification is associated with the same Firebase project. If you obtained the token from a different project, it won't work.
4. **Check Project Setup**:
   Make sure that your Firebase project has the necessary APIs enabled, specifically the Firebase Cloud Messaging API.
5. **Check Service Account Key**:
   Ensure that the `serviceAccountKey.json` file you're using is properly downloaded from the Firebase Console and that it corresponds to the project you're working with.

Here's a revised version of your code with inline comments for better clarity:

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://<your-project-id>.firebaseio.com" // Update with your actual project URL
});

const message = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Hello from Firebase!',
        body: 'This is a push notification from Firebase.'
    },
    token: 'ekBu_n:APA91bEAXiyJvEbk5Vb4u7tJgCjFXGHL6sNypCgYTP3qPfy1nC2Sw9Q7H6zRDo8-AM31l6GI-twJe72t4z4k-hGy1KNgtpsWaXeP2tieH_J7XyZYDr5LWevh5g2TnOhEgNafnW0t-o0d' // Replace with the specific device token
};

// Send the message
admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Notification sent successfully:', response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sending notification:', error);
    });
```

If you've followed these steps and the issue persists, please ensure that you're using the correct configuration and tokens for your Firebase project and FCM. If you're still facing difficulties, consider reaching out to Firebase support for more personalized assistance.